# Any one have URDU language js library working with ckeditor?

Tags: ckeditor, phonetics, urdu

Any one have URDU language JS library working with ckeditor ? i can pay him i need that library very importantly.
i have used this library `http://ckeditor.com/forums/Plugins/Urdu-input` it works in Mozilla but didn't work in chrome, in chrome it shows me characters but not to make words.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adding different language plugins, where the words are different or may be wrong. You can just use your system keyboard languages and in CKEditor use content direction (i.e. contentsLangDirection) as per the languages. I did it as below :

```
$(function(){
    $("#Language_secondary").change(function(){
        resetCKEditorAccordingToLanguage(CKEDITOR.instances.editor4, this.value)
    });
});

function resetCKEditorAccordingToLanguage(ckeditorObj, Language_secondary){
    switch(Language_secondary){
        case 'ARABIAN':
        case 'URDU':
            ckeditorObj.config.contentsLangDirection = 'rtl';
            break;
        default :
            ckeditorObj.config.contentsLangDirection = 'ltr';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://ckeditor.com/forums/Plugins/Urdu-input use this plugin but for old version of ckeditor  it works perfectly

Comment: @Hassan Shafique Thank you for help. But as per the link they are associating keycode to some texts. And i don't know exactly that those keys are correct or not so better to use system keyboard.

Another case there is lots of languages which are reading from right to left so for them also needs to add different characters, which is not generalized way.

Comment: this.value will return the value inputted by user.. not keyboard language.